# Check the status of In-App Subscription in Android

Tags: java, php, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have created an application in which there is in-app purchases which has monthly auto renewal.. on first time successful payment i have called a web-service in which i have made the user to premium class.

Now if the user has cancelled the payment manually from the google server, how could i know that user has cancelled his/her subscription.

Is there is some PHP code query or from android i have to called something in background to check the status??

Thank you in advace

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check the purchased subscriptions inside the app via

**Edit:** For subscriptions use "subs", for inapp-purchases use "inapp" e.g.:

Inapp-Purchases: `mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);`

Subscriptions: `mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "subs", null);`

See also `Querying for Purchased Items` at http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

So you can implement a task in your app where you check if the user still has a subscription. If not, you can remove the premium status. Moreover this information could be useful for you:

> When the user cancels a subscription, Google Play does not offer a refund for the current billing cycle. Instead, it allows the user to have access to the canceled subscription until the end of the current billing cycle, at which time it terminates the subscription. For example, if a user purchases a monthly subscription and cancels it on the 15th day of the cycle, Google Play will consider the subscription valid until the end of the 30th day (or other day, depending on the month).

source: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html under `subscription cancelled`

Hope this could help you

**Edit2:** Because the AIDL library which is mentioned in my answer is deprecated and deactivated in the future, it is recommended to switch to the new [Google Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#java).

Comment: Your suggestion is wrong. mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null); is used for one-time purchase. You should use "subs" instead of "inapp" to get subscriptions

Comment: Thank you for the information. I corrected my answer :-)

Comment: These methods are not available in new Play Billing Library. Any way to do it?

Comment: Thanks. I am getting old cached purchase result. I've got gmail receipt the renewal successful. How long it takes to get the latest result. Any idea?

Answer (score 9):

I haven't tested this, but could you use the `autoRenewing` field in INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA?

> If true, the subscription is active, and will automatically renew on the next billing date. **If false, indicates that the user has canceled the subscription**.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getBuyIntent

Apparently, the `autoRenewing` field was added or at least documented [in the beginning of 2015](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b5e00e5%5E!/).

Answer (score -1):

Check the getPurchases() method [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html). Or if you use Android Studio and have the source code downloaded just press `Ctrl` + `Q` on `IInAppBillingService.getPurchases` method

Comment: It gives purchase state not subscription status after it has been canceled from google play app.